# How to determine C-rate for DIY batteries?

Tags: batteries, measurement, c-rate

I am investigating some DIY battery chemistries and construction, as such they do not have a known C-rate.  How would one measure this?  How is it determined for commercial batteries?  There seems to be little information on this and as it impacts safe battery use due to thermal runaway I'd like to know how to measure this.  Please no answers along the lines of "just buy commercial batteries" or "Why do you want to make your own batteries?"   Just how to actually do it.

Comment: The C trading is supplier advertising and has no real objective engineering meaning.

Comment: Investigate what level of charge/discharge damages your design of battery, then back it off to get an acceptable safety margin?

Answer (score 4):

1. Choose the ambient temperature for your battery tests. Hopefully representative of its intended application, but maybe not.
2. Arbitrarily decide an operating time interval. Hopefully something representative of your intended application. Or maybe not.
3. Decide on what battery state you deem "dead".
4. Run tests at the chosen ambient temperature to find out what current is required to discharge a fully charged battery and have it be "dead" at the end of the time interval you chose in #1.
5. Use the time interval and the discharge current in #4 to calculate your mAh.
6. Choose the maximum temperature you decide your battery can operate at.
7. Calculate the allowable temperature rise from the temperatures in #1 and #6.
8. Run tests at the chosen ambient temperature to find out how much discharge current is required to reach and maintain the condition chosen in #7. Or, the condition might not be temperature but some other damage phenomena that kicks in earlier.
9. Use that discharge current and your mAh to calculate your C-rating.

Notice all the things you get to choose arbitrarily.

In particular, note the effect of the time interval chosen for the test. If the manufacturer has chosen 10 h for their mAh test, and your actual discharge current is 2C, that doesn't mean your battery will last \$\frac{1}{2}\$ hour. It will be less due to internal resistance. Conversely if your discharge rate is \$\frac{1}{20}\$C, it doesn't mean your battery will last 20 hours. It will last longer. If your discharge current is \$\frac{1}{10}\$C then your battery will last 10h because that's what the manufacturer back-calculated the mAh from.

And if the manufacturer's intended application is a particularly cold or warm environment, the temperature rise they choose may deviate from the difference between the maximum allowable battery temperature and room temperature.

Or you might only care about marketing so choose common conditions not representative of the application that give you the best possible ratings. Or you might be a bit more lax on your damage and temperature criteria resulting in reduced product lifetime, which will give you better ratings.